# How to pass a TextBox value to a UserControl in just the same form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using one form with a DataGridView and a UserControl. So, the process goes like this:

When the DataGridView is clicked, it passes the ID of the person to a TextBox which we need for inserting it to a table. My problem is how can we pass the value from the TextBox to the UserControl?

We can't figure it out. I've been searching but most of the answers are about two different forms. Ours is, in one form and we need the value of the TextBox to pass it on the UserControl below it.

Comment: `userControl1.SomeProperty = textBox1.Text` ?

Comment: Please provide more details about your scenario. Maybe a small code which illustrates better your goal

Comment: This is like a huge form for registration. So since we can't  modify the size of the windows form, we have used user control and add it on the form. We just need to pass the id from the form to the user control below so we can add it successfully.

Comment: Add some of your code and Screenshots to your issue.

Comment: @xhei Did you try what vasily.sib has suggested? Are you sure that the [Access Modifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers) of the UserControl's controls are either `Public` or `Internal`?

Comment: I'm really sorry for the confusion. It's my first time to use user control. I did not expect that this would cause trouble in building this project.  Here is what I'm trying to explain. I hope this shows up. I don't know how to paste a screenshot :'( https://snag.gy/aFnopL.jpg

Comment: @xhei, don't post screenshots (they are useless), post some code. It is totally unclear what you asking for. If you already have a method, that passes the ID of the person to a TextBox, why don't you pass this ID to your UserControl same time?

Comment: Make a Public Method/Property in the USerControl. When you update the TextBox text, also pass the same value to the UC using the public Method/Property. e.g.,  `[MyUserControl].[MyPublicProperty] = [The same value that goes into the TextBox];` Use the value passed to the Method/Property to update the TextBox inside the UC.

Comment: Hi everyone! I figure it out by using the name of the user control plus the textbox name and use the code for datagridview when clicked. Thank you all for your help.

fp1.pid.Text = pdt.Rows[pdt.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[1].Value.ToString();